# No puedo atrapar un error de promise AngularFire

Tags: angular, firebase

He estado intentar atrapar un error que me aparece en consola que esta relacionado con el método de signUpWithEmailandPassword(), he tratado de utilizar try and catch o usando los mismos metodos de then/catch hasta promise(reject,resolve)

Código:

```
 return this.afat.signInWithEmailAndPassword(correo,pass)
      .then(()=> {this.router.navigate(['home'])}, err => {
        console.log('error');
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('oops');
      });
```

Error que me arroja en consola(El cual no quiero que muestre)

```
core.js:6498 
        
       ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted. (auth/user-not-found).
FirebaseError: Firebase: There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted. (auth/user-not-found).
```

Comment: No lo imprimas `console.log(error)`

Comment: que es `this.afat`? Me imagino que hay un `pipe` que contiene un `catchError`

Comment: @Lobos Sigue apareciendo, y si llegara a imprimir solo muestra el mismo error pero en texto.

Comment: @Legna es una forma de llamar a AngularFireAuth

Comment: Intentaste con un pipe y catchError antes del subscribe?

Comment: @Legna Esos métodos no existen en la funcion, solo then/catch/finally

Comment: Mi error. Pero , por que estas usando promesas en angular?lo común es usar `subscribe`...

Comment: Revisa tu codigo.....>this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword>......tambien hay distintas versiones web de firebase con lo cual el codigo anterior tambien se modifica https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth?hl=es

Comment: @Legna las promesas son propias de javascript, y Angular es un framework de javascript, por lo tanto se pueden, y es muy común, usar promesas. Usar `subscribe` es para observables

Comment: @AndresGardiol, nop, lo que es común es usar observables. https://angular.io/guide/observables

Comment: Por supuesto que es lo común. Pero si consumes un servicio que devuelve una promesa y no un observable, entonces puedes usar una promesa y listo